# Why does this perl code checking an if clause always default to the first if?

Tags: perl

```
for ( ;; ) {
    print "Command>  ";
    $result = <STDIN>;
    print "\n";
    $answer = 0;
    if ( $result == "add" ) {
        for ( $counter = 1; $counter >= 1; $counter++ ) {
            print "Enter the $counter th number:  ";
            $NumberToAdd = <STDIN>;
            if ( $NumberToAdd != "NONE" ) {
                $answer = $answer + $NumberToAdd;
            } else {
                print "\n";
                last;
            }
        }
    } elsif ( $result == "subtract" ) {
        for ( $counter = 1; $counter >= 1; $counter++ ) {
            print "Enter the $counter th number:  ";
            $NumberToSub = <STDIN>;
            if ( $NumberToSub != "NONE" ) {
                $answer = $answer - $NumberToSub;
            } else {
                print "\n";
                last;
            }
        }
    } elsif ( $result == "quit" ) {
        last;
    } else {
        print "Error. Please enter add, subtract, or quit, and press Enter. \n";
    }
    print "The answer to your operation was: $answer \n";
}
```

Now if you enter in quit at the terminal line, it will still go into the first if statement.  Or if you enter asdfsa it will still go into the first if statement.  Etc.

EDIT: The new, correct working code shown below:

```
for ( ;; ) {
    print "Command>  ";
    chomp( $result = <STDIN> );
    $answer = 0;
    if ( $result eq 'add' ) {
        for ( $counter = 1; $counter >= 1; $counter++ ) {
            print "Enter number $counter to add:  ";
            chomp( $NumberToAdd = <STDIN> );
            if ( $NumberToAdd ne 'NONE' ) {
                $answer = $answer + $NumberToAdd;
            } else {
                last;
            }
        }
    } elsif ( $result eq 'subtract' ) {
        for ( $counter = 1; $counter >= 1; $counter++ ) {
            if ( $counter == 1 ) {
                print "Enter the first number to begin subtracting from:  ";
                chomp( $NumberToSubtractFrom = <STDIN> );
                if ( $NumberToSubtractFrom eq 'NONE' ) {
                    last;
                }
            } elsif ( $counter != 1 ) {
                $countertodisplay = $counter - 1;
                print "Enter number $countertodisplay to subtract:  ";
                chomp( $NumberToSub = <STDIN> );
                if ( $NumberToSub eq 'NONE' ) {
                    last;
                } else {
                    $NumberToSubtractFrom = $NumberToSubtractFrom - $NumberToSub;
                }
            }
        }
        $answer = $NumberToSubtractFrom;
    } elsif ( $result eq 'quit' ) {
        last;
    } else {
        print "Error. Please enter add, subtract, or quit, and press Enter. \n";
    }
    print "The answer to your operation was: $answer \n";
}
```

Comment: You should not edit your question to hide the errors after an answer is given. You even added the `chomp` question. This makes the given answer look very redundant. If your question has been answered, click the checkmark next to the appropriate answer. If you have follow up questions, post a new question.

Comment: Alright, instead I will just post a clear edit where the correct new code is shown.  Being able to see the correct new code is very helpful to me when I view SO questions, so I will do it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wrong operator is used as ..

> .. Perl has two versions of some operators, one for numeric and one for string comparison. For example $a == $b compares two numbers for equality, and $a eq $b compares two strings.

See [Equality Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) for the details; pay attention to the words *numerically* and *stringwise*. The values are *numerically*-equal, even though they are different strings and *stringwise*-different.

Here is quick excerpt:

> Binary "==" returns true if the left argument is *numerically equal* to the right argument.
>
> Binary "eq" returns true if the left argument is *stringwise equal* to the right argument.

The first step is to replace all the incorrect usages of `==` with `eq`.

In addition the code should *remove the trailing newline* from $result as `"foo" eq "foo\n"` is false. See [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) for how this can be easily done.

Comment: Okay I've made this change.  And then I suppose I will need to use chomp sine you mentioned removing the newline.